# HTML - Table -vertical position text within cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I would like to have text within a table cell to be positioned a little bit higher, near the top. Please take a look at the provided screenshot. You can see in the TD below Column 1 how I want it to look like:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/38f1aru6/1/

HTML:

```
<table class="table_text">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <center>
          <b>Title</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column1</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column2</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column3</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column4</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>lirum</td>
      <td>larum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.td_content
{

}

.yellow_marked
{
  background-color: yellow;
}

table
{
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
td
{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

I'm  new to HTML and CSS... and a little bit shocked how complicated some simple styling can be.

My first guess was text alignment within a cell... vertical-align? Didn't work.
Then I tried to use an element with absolute positioning within an element with relative positioning. It did work ... almost ... but the text did flow out of the cell.

I would be very grateful if you could show me the right direction to solve this (easy?) task.

**Edit:**

I want to keep the yellow bar in the same position, but I want to move the text within the bar upward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from comments that you want to keep the yellow bar in the same position, but you want to move the text in it upward. That is not hard, but it does involve adding extra markup; otherwise it's impossible to separate the text from the background in that way. So, here you go.

```css
.yellow_marked {
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* added css */

caption {
  font-weight: bold
}

.yellow_marked>span {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_text">
  <caption>
    Title
  </caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column2
      </th>
      <th>
        Column3
      </th>
      <th>
        Column4
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked"><span>Cell content here</span></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>lirum</td>
      <td>larum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, I'm sorry for changing your HTML, but you were using non-semantic markup for the title and the column headers, not to mention obsolete and unnecessary elements; couldn't bear to leave those in.

If you want, you can use the new CSS with the old HTML though.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Lister. After the edit you provided the answer i was looking for. Its easier than i thought. A span within a span and then position the inner span relative to the outer span. Oh and dont worry about changing my HTML, im always ready to improve myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `vertical-align:super` on the `span` inside ( on `.td-content` )

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38f1aru6/3/)

let me know if this is what you want

```css
.td_content
{
  vertical-align:super;
}

.yellow_marked
{
  background-color: yellow;
}

table
{
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
td
{
  border: 1px solid;

}
```

```html
<table class="table_text">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <center>
          <b>Title</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column1</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column2</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column3</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column4</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>lirum</td>
      <td>larum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this solutions moves the yellow background too. Please take a look at my screenshot. I only want to move the text up, without moving the yellow background. And i can't use background-color on the cell. The yellow background should roughly have the same size as the text.

Comment: Wait, you want to keep the yellow block in the same position? That wasn't clear from the question, nor from the screen shot. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: My bad. I noticed it after i tried out the presented solutions. But the screenshot is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:top` works.

```css
.td_content
{
  
}

.yellow_marked
{
  background-color: yellow;
}

table
{
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
td
{
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top; /* To move the text to the top */
  padding-top: 5px; /* To create a gap at the top */
}
```

```html
<table class="table_text">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <center>
          <b>Title</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column1</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column2</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column3</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column4</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>lirum</td>
      <td>larum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the yellow background to the `td` instead. And then use a negative margin on the `span` element.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72bgfz22/1/)

```css
.td_content {}

.yellow_marked {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow_marked span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_text">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <center>
          <b>Title</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column1</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column2</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column3</b>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <b>Column4</b>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow_marked">
        <span class="td_content">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="td_content yellow_marked">Cell content here</span>
      </td>
      <td>lirum</td>
      <td>larum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this works... but what can i do if i only want to have a yellow background for the text, not the whole cell?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. See Mr. Lister's answer